# collecting information from a dbcheck log

Tags: oracle, batch-file, variables, logging

my problem is that i want to collect informations from a database check log like Database name, version and alot more with Cmd

Here is a short example of this log:

```
########################################################################
#               Oracle Database Check Report                           #
########################################################################
Date Of This Report:

13 June      2018  12:58

Database Name:

XE

Database Version:

11.2.0.2.0

Database Characterset:

AL32UTF8

Database Language:

AMERICAN

...
```

So i want to search for several things to be saved to another file to insert these in a table later. Whats the best way to archive this? 
The Main problem is the search for this things in the log because using

```
/find "Database Name:" xxx.log
```

just gives me one line

```
----------- xxx.log
Database Name:
```

Need to get the Database name below.
But i'm missing batch know-how

Platform: Windows.
Database: Oracle.

Comment: Your question, `Whats the best way to archive this?` is off topic because it is **primarily opinion-based**. Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Please share your afforts by providing a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question! Also read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch isn't the language of choice to condense your reports with regular expressions.

I'd suggest to use PowerShell. This script returns PropertyValue pairs you can process further.

```
$File = '.\OracleDataBaseCheckReport.txt'

$PropertyValue = (Get-Content $File -raw) `
     -Replace "(?smi)^(Da.*?):\s*\r?\n\s*\r?\n(.*?)$",'"$1"="$2"' `
     -Replace ' +',' ' `
     -Split '\r?\n' | 
   Select-String '"="'
```

---

```
PS> $PropertyValue

"Date Of This Report"="13 June 2018 12:58"
"Database Name"="XE"
"Database Version"="11.2.0.2.0"
"Database Characterset"="AL32UTF8"
"Database Language"="AMERICAN"
```

Comment: Thanks!, i will try to work with this and give a reply when i have time.